# Question about present perfect continuous and teaching it

Tags: word-meaning

*The car has been giving me trouble from the start.*

How do you simplify this grammar in a simple manner. I know it in advance but a great deal of difficulty teaching it to my mother. I am going to have to be her tutor in a short time.

A million thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*The car **gave** me trouble on the day I bought it.*
*It **continued to give** me trouble from that day on.*
*It **is still giving** me trouble today.*

*It **has been giving me** trouble since the day I bought it.*

Answer (score 0):

This is your third question about teaching your mother. If this is the case, I *suggest* that you avoid complex sentences which include *has been* etc. structure. You may make them simple or may switch to colloquial language. This is because here, the purpose is to **convey** the message and not to proofread the sentence!

Back to the question, again, there could be many ways to say this but I'm telling you my way.

> The car is giving me trouble from the day I purchased/bought it.